# Unable to update field in Firestore emulator document with new Date()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the client-side, I am running firebase emulators and trying to update a document by adding a timestamp field.

Here's the code to run the emulators:

```
 const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 Firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
 Firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
 Firebase.storage().useEmulator('localhost', 9199);
 Firebase.firestore().useEmulator('localhost', 8080);
 firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```

Here's the code that creates the document then tries to update it:

```
await Firebase.firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .doc('id')
  .set({ x: 'test' });

await Firebase.firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .doc('id')
  .update({ y: new Date() });
```

Creation of the document works properly (see screenshot below) but updating it with a field that has value of type `Date` does not work.

[image]

Also, here is the debugging output in `firebase-debug.log` :

```
WARNING: invalid message: {"streamToken":"MQ==","writes":[{"update":{"name":"projects/emulators-*****-test/databases/(default)/documents/collection/id","fields":{"y":{"timestampValue":{"seconds":1626973406,"nanos":407000000}}}},"updateMask":{"fieldPaths":["y"]},"currentDocument":{"exists":true}}]}
Jul 22, 2021 7:03:26 PM com.google.net.webchannel.server.common.ChannelProcessor run
WARNING: Failed to consume the event.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: JsonObject
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.JsonToProtoConverter.toWriteRequest(JsonToProtoConverter.java:33)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter$FirestoreWriteHandler.onMessage(FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter$FirestoreWriteHandler.onMessage(FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter.java:111)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.onMessage(ChannelInternalImpl.java:485)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.deliverMessage(ForwardChannel.java:114)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.processPendingRequest(ForwardChannel.java:93)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.consume(ForwardChannel.java:67)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.add(ForwardChannel.java:60)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.handleRequestParams(ChannelInternalImpl.java:260)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.processSessionRequest(ChannelInternalImpl.java:317)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.handle(ChannelInternalImpl.java:142)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.consume(ChannelInternalImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.common.ChannelProcessor.run(ChannelProcessor.java:80)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: JsonObject
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.jsonformatfork.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1348)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.jsonformatfork.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:452)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.JsonToProtoConverter.toWriteRequest(JsonToProtoConverter.java:30)
    ... 12 more
```

`firebase version is 8.7.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Firestore Timestamp

```js
const fireDate = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

await Firebase.firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .doc('id')
  .update({ y: fireDate });
```

Also turns out this is an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5047) with the SDK. Although it works for me perfectly on version `8.7.1`, try `8.6.2` just to try it out.

Comment: This is also not working!
It only works when I use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` which does not give me ability to use specific dates.

Comment: @Hatem can you try with version 8.6.2 once? That indeed was an issue with the SDK.

Comment: This worked using version `8.6.2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
await Firebase.firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .doc('id')
  .update({ y: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
```